# How to edit the table record due to login user

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

The problem I encountered for edit multiple records of the table according to the login user id. When I edit the one record and update the record into the database, the id is 0, as well as whatever I click the edit button only can edit the first record. How can I edit and update the multiple of the table as each row?

```
$login_user=$_SESSION['id'];
```

Comment: If your problem is getting the id, then this problem is not with database but with HTML and or javascript.

Comment: Yes, you are corrected . My problem is on the SQL statement. I don't know how the user join statement to link the another table and edit and update multiple record of the table  as each row.

Comment: If the database query is the issue it would be helpful to include an example of what you are working with. Is there a single ID column that is consistent across all the tables that need updating? If so, would you provide the name of each table and the column names that you are updating?

Comment: From the question text, **your problem is an HTML button**. Be consistent.

Comment: it is a single ID column that is consistent one the tables that need update. my question is I want to update the multiple record of on the one table due to the login user id. Now I  only can do it can show all record according to login user id, but only can update first record only, when I click edit button of second record it still show the first record details.

Comment: my problem is an HTML button? Can you explain more detai?